# Optimizing Nokogiri Scraper In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have a Nokogiri scraper set up below. Everything works fine, it's just really slow. I have been researching how to make it faster and have come across using threads, moving it to a background process, save to db and cache it, I am just not sure what route to take, or where to start really. And advice or direction would be greatly appreciated. You can see a live version at http://clstorycloud.com The scraper grabs blog images and posts from different blogs on the same domain and currently scrapes in real time.

### Model

```
class Photocloud < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :start_urls
  attr_accessor :images, :paths

  def initialize(start_urls)
    @start_urls = start_urls
    @paths = []
    @images = []
  end

  def scrape
    start_urls.each do |start_url|
      blog = Nokogiri::HTML(open(start_url))
      scrape_images(blog)
      scrape_paths(blog)
    end
  end


  private
  def scrape_images(blog)
    images = blog.xpath('//*[@class="postBody"]/div[1]//img/@src')
    images.each do |image|
      @images << image
    end
  end

  def scrape_paths(blog)      
    story_path = blog.xpath('//*[@class="postTitle"]/a/@href')
    story_path.each do |path|
      @paths << path
    end
  end
end
```

### View

```
<div id="container" class="container">
  <% @paths.zip(@images).each do |url, img|%>
  <div class="item tranz ">
    <a href="<%= url %>" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.cltampa.com<%= img %>"></a>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Controller

```
def index
  start_urls = %w[http://cltampa.com/blogs/potlikker 
    http://cltampa.com/blogs/artbreaker 
    http://cltampa.com/blogs/politicalanimals 
    http://cltampa.com/blogs/earbuds 
    http://cltampa.com/blogs/dailyloaf]
  scraper = Photocloud.new(start_urls)
  scraper.scrape
  @images = scraper.images
  @paths = scraper.paths
end
```

Comment: Do you want your index page to load faster or you want the scraper runs faster?

Comment: Hi @StevenTen, I would like the index page to load faster. So after the first blog is scraped, ideally the images would start to load, while the rest followed, something to that extent.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making pararell requests using [typheus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#making-parallel-requests).

Right now your `scrape` method got to finish one request before starting the next one, you can optimize that if you do pararell requests (send all them at once, instead of send one after the other).

Using `typheous` your code would look like:

```
hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.hydra  
start_urls.each do |start_url|
  # Build a request object representing the actual request you want to send and add it to the queue.
  hydra.queue(Typhoeus::Request.new(start_url))
end
# Then, run all the queued request in pararell.
hydra.run

# Then, you can get all requests response like this
responses = requests.map do |request| 
  request.response.body
  # Any other code here
end
```

With this approach you can optimize you **scraper** . Lets say you have 10 request to process and each one takes 10 seconds. With the actual approach the total processing time will be 100 seconds. By sending all your request in pararell the total processing time will be only 10.

You can find all the documentation about `typheous` [here](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus). To go straigh to the section about pararell requests click [here](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#making-parallel-requests).

Comment: Great thank you. Going to check this out, will post back when I get it going.

Comment: Would I just have to update my scrape method? Any chance you can elaborate based on my original code, a little stuck on how to build it in.